# How to change 'From' address and target calendar when creating events with Google API

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I've managed to install the google API using composer and ZF2, and have successfully worked through the tribulation that is getting the P12 key, configuring the app, and configuring the Google_Client instance.

I've also managed to create events like so:

```
/** @var \Google_Service_Calendar $calendar */
        $calendar = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('GoogleCalendar');
        $event = new \Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
        $event->setSummary( "This is a test" );

        $dts = new \Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
        $dts->setDateTime( date( "Y-m-d\\TH:i:s.000-04:00" ) );
        $event->setStart( $dts );

        $dte = new \Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
        $dte->setDateTime( date( "Y-m-d\\TH:i:s.000-04:00", time() + 1800 ) );
        $event->setEnd( $dte );

        $att = array();
        foreach( $emails as $e )
        {
            $attendee = new \Google_Service_Calendar_EventAttendee();
            $attendee->setEmail( $e );
            $att[] = $attendee;
        }

        $event->setAttendees( $att );

        $x = $calendar->events->insert( "primary", $event, array( 'sendNotifications' => true ) );
        return new JsonModel( array( 'success' => true ) );
```

The invitation comes from the application's client email, but I'd like to make it come from a particular email.  How can I change the invitation?

Also, we subscribe to Google for Business ourselves; is it possible to create events within our business calendars rather than 'primary' on the app itself?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking [at the actually API documentation at Google](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert), I'm not seeing a property to change who the calendar invite comes from. I'm not sure that would be a great thing to be able to do, you could then setup calendar events/invites from the CEO of a company about the company going out of business or some other crazy calendar invite without approval.

Your best bet would be to authorize the application for the account you want to use, then use the token from that account to insert calendar events.

Comment: Well, we can add those CEO's as organizers without any strict verification, but the point is valid.  Do you have any info on what you wrote, be it "Authorize the app for the account you want to use"?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Saeven Instead of using a token for the application alone that you've generated, you would have the account you'd want to send the invites from obtain a authorization token using Oauth. Once you have the token, your application would be able to act on their behalf. Take a look at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth for a little more information.